# How can I tell if I'm in a remote PowerShell session?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I would like to execute code that is specific to remote PSSessions. That is, the code doesn't apply locally, but applies to all remote sessions.

Is there any environment variable, function or cmdlet that would effectively return true if I'm in an active PSSession and false if I'm running locally?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if the `$PSSenderInfo` variable exists. From *about_Automatic_Variables*:

> #### `$PSSenderInfo`
>
> Contains information about the user who started the PSSession,
>   including  the user identity and the time zone of the originating
>   computer. This variable is available only in PSSessions.
>
> The `$PSSenderInfo` variable includes a user-configurable property,
>   `ApplicationArguments`, which, by default, contains only the
>   `$PSVersionTable` from the originating session. To add data to the
>   `ApplicationArguments` property, use the `ApplicationArguments` parameter
>   of the `New-PSSessionOption` cmdlet.

Comment: depending on your use case you may also want to check `$PSSenderInfo.ConnectionString -ne 'http://localhost'` because `Start-Job {$null -ne $PSSenderinfo} | receive-job -wait -AutoRemoveJob` is `$true`

Answer (score 0):

You could also test using this:

If ( (Test-Path variable:PSSenderInfo)
        -and ($Null -ne $PSSenderInfo) 
        -and ($PSSenderInfo.GetType().Name -eq 'PSSenderInfo') ) {
    Write-Host -Object "This script cannot be run within an active PSSession"
    Exit
}

This was not my initial finding, but it helped with "variable PSSenderInfo not set" issue, if it doesn't exist.

Comment: No need for all this tests. This command line is sufficient: `if($PSSenderInfo){'I am in a remote session'}`